# How to only display one info window when click on marker?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

```
var i;
var marker = [];
var infowindow = [];

for(i=0; i<results.length ; i++ ){
marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
  position: results[i].geometry.location,
  map: map
});

infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
  content: "test" + i
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function(num) {
  return function() {
      infowindow[num].open(map, marker[num]);
  }
}(i)); 

}
```

I wrote some code to have different info window content when click on each marker (test1, test2, test3....) and the info window will remain on screen even i click another marker.

How to only show one infowindow when click on each marker?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Google Maps JS API v3 - Simple Multiple Marker Example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3059044/google-maps-js-api-v3-simple-multiple-marker-example)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remember the currently opened window, and close it when you need to open another one, similar to this:

```
var curInfoWindow;
google.maps.event.addListener(marker[i], 'click', function(num) {
  return function() {
    if (curInfoWindow != null) {
        curInfoWindow.close();
    }
    curInfoWindow = infowindow[num];

    infowindow[num].open(map, marker[num]);
  }
}(i));
```